# which country launched N-95 mask for the first time?

Tags: medicine

I did much searching about the N-95 mask but couldn't find any clue about its main  country, i.e. who launched it. Can anyone let me know which country really launched it?

Comment: I'm not responsible for having this question moved over here, and the migration target site seems of dubious suitability. Probably best asked on engineering SE or just history SE (the latter site is often a horror show of newbie biting, so good luck with that).

Comment: Regarding the question itself, it may be ill-posed because dust masks have been around for a long time. "N95" is a US standard, in other places there's [FF]P2 etc.

Comment: You should (at least here, perhaps other sites too) tell what N-95 is all about.

Answer (score 3):

According to the article [The untold origin story of the N95 mask](https://www.fastcompany.com/90479846/the-untold-origin-story-of-the-n95-mask):

> The first single-use N95 “dust” respirator as we know it was developed by 3M, according to the company, and approved on May 25, 1972.

The article details the use and development of the precursors to the N95, noting that initial use of the N95 was for industrial applications.  It was the appearance of drug resistant tuberculosis and HIV in the 1990s which brought the mask into clinical use.